# Buscar informações não diretamente relacionadas no Banco de Dados

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, tabela-banco-de-dados

Gostaria de selecionar de um banco de dados que possui as tabelas Livro, Autor e Editora, os atributos **Nome_autor**, **Sobrenome_autor**, **Titulo_livro** e **Nome_editora** de tabelas que não estão diretamente relacionadas(por assim dizer), esse é a estrutura do banco;

```
create table if not exists Livro(
Id_livro tinyint auto_increment,
Titulo_livro varchar(45) not null,
Data_publicacao_livro date not null,
primary key(Id_livro)) default charset = utf8;

create table if not exists Autor(
Id_autor tinyint auto_increment,
Nome_autor varchar(45) not null,
Sobrenome_autor varchar(45) not null,
primary key(Id_autor)) default charset = utf8;

create table if not exists Editora(
Id_editora tinyint auto_increment,
Nome_editora varchar(45) not null,
primary key(Id_editora)) default charset = utf8;

/*Um livro pode ter mais de um autor bem como um mesmo titulo pode ser publicado por mais de uma editora 
dessa forma temos um relacionamento de muitos para muitos com cada uma das tabelas*/

create table if not exists Publicado( -- Essa tabela relaciona o livro com a editora
Id_livro tinyint not null,
Id_editora tinyint not null,
primary key(Id_livro, Id_editora),
foreign key(Id_livro) references Livro(Id_livro),
foreign key(Id_editora) references Editora(Id_editora));

create table if not exists Escrito( -- Relaciona o livro com os autores
Id_livro tinyint not null,
Id_autor tinyint not null,
primary key(Id_livro, Id_autor),
foreign key(Id_livro) references Livro(Id_livro),
foreign key(Id_autor) references Autor(Id_autor));
```

Eu uso um simples inner join? ou é necessário que seja feita uma subconsulta?

Comment: A propósito eu uso o MariaDB

Comment: Não está claro o que você quer fazer, que informações você quer ler?

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que seja apenas um simples select com joins:

```
Select 
e.id_livro,
a.nome_autor,
a.sobrenome_autor,
l.titulo_livro,
coalesce(d.nome_editora,'Não Publicado') as nome_editora
from escrito e
inner join livro l on l.id_livro = e.id_livro
inner join autor a on a.id_autor = e.id_autor
left outer join publicado p on p.id_livro = e.id_livro
left outer join editora d on d.id_editora = p.id_editora
```

Comment: Acredito que a solução seja essa proposta pelo Rovann

Comment: pra que serve esse coalesce?
Desculpe sou muito principiante em SQL

Comment: considerei que há a possibilidade de um livro não ter sido publicado, logo não estaria na tabela `publicado` (fora esse motivo, não vejo porque da existência dessa tabela) por isso utilizei o left outer join para trazer a tabela, e se caso a coluna `nome_editora` vier nulo, significa que não foi publicado. O coalesce retorna o primeiro valor não nulo que estiver nos seus parâmetros.